# Any Prolog implementation that allows left recursion?

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I wonder if there is any Prolog implementation that allows left recursion in clauses.  My intuition is that if the implementation uses a breadth-first goal search, it may support left recursion.  But I am not quite sure.  Note that I do not care much about efficiency.

Comment: or with iterative deepening. well, you said you don't care about efficiency... :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Will.  Iterative deepening actually works better.  I tried the BF extension of Ciao with a small example, got stackoverflow (no pun ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, but Prolog uses depth first search by design (see SLDNF resolution [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution)) and with good reasons, then that limitation is not easily avoided.

OTOH, Ciao Prolog offers an appropriate [extension](http://ciao-lang.org/docs/1.14/13646/CiaoDE-1.14.2-13646_ciao.html/bf_doc.html).

You can simulate breadth first recursion, using a meta interpreter, as done for instance [here](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/acomip/acomip.html) for a left recursive DCG (left recursive grammars are a common case), but it's not generally an easy way to follow.

IMO the most common extension that could approximate/satisfy your request, is *tabling*, you can find it in YAP Prolog, XSB, B-Prolog.

Comment: a link to some material on tabling would really be helpful here. :)